# Tunnel through an http proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, tunnel

My college has an intranet set up with outside communication possible only through a certain (HTTP proxy) ip. The http proxy also uses filtering. But Tor works (with bridges) Psyphon too works. I need a way to tunnel all TCP and UDP traffic through it in order to play FPS games.

(By port scanning the public ip i found out that port 21 is open. Should this be of any help ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a serious FPS player, don't bother.  Proxies will add significant lag and instability to your connection.     This is particularly true because you will be routing UDP over TCP - while this works, it defeats the purpose and many of the benefits

Port 21 is associated with FTP - are you certain this is unfiltered, and not just unfiltered for a particular host ?  If so, its a better candidate port then 80 as you may not be going through a proxy - or if you do it is probably more responsive.  Still not a good idea though.

If you are very dedicated to your lost cause (and being kicked out of college), you should also look at a DNS tunnel.

If you still want to proceed, this [can be done using OpenVPN](http://mwiki.yyovkov.net/index.php/OpenVPN_over_HTTP_Proxy).

Comment: I have already tried using a SoftEther VPN but for some reason it doesn't connect through the proxy at all. The error pops up as soon as u give the command. I was under the impression that it uses HTTPS over port 443 to  connect to the servers.

Comment: I am not certain about port 21 being unfiltered for everyone or just a particular host. How do I check ?

Comment: I suggest you don't - you are going to get yourself into trouble.  The first thing to do is to try ftp'ing to external sites, and see if they work.  If they do, then you probably need to set up an FTP server and have a look at the logs - this might tell you something - particularly if you look at IP's and traffic flows - but unless you know what you are doing (and understand the FTP protocol) you may draw the incorrect conclusion.